Best approach for showing custom data in the Volt template dashboard for Django
I am currently building a personal app and would like to use the Volt template for Django.
The link to the template is here:
https://tb-volt-dashboard-django.appseed-srv1.com/dashboard.html
I want to update the chart in the dashboard to use custom generated data from the view.
What's the best approach/ recommended approach to do that?
I see currently that the data is being hard-coded in the volt.js file in the Volt directories.

“Best” is a matter of opinion and circumstances.  The link to the template is here I see a login page.

You can use the default credentials to login. It should be mentioned on the page itself above the login prompt.

For me, most important is flexibility and ease of populating the elements with data from the index.
